# Dependency Conflict Between Slither And Brownie

Tags: python, brownie, slither

I have encountered strange issue and I'm not sure how can I fix it permanently. I had brownie (similar to hardhat) tool installed and once I have installed slither those 2 seems to have some conflicts, because my brownie stopped working (library is working fine), but all brownie commands like run etc. stopped working. I have figured out that reinstalling brownie with simple checking this package by pip install eth-brownie solves the issue, but after that when I wanted to run yarn slither it stopped working... and I had to run pip install slither-analyzer and what should be obvious now my brownie stopped working again...

Does someone know how to have both installed and working at the same time? Both are using Python. Some errors below:

Running brownie while slither is installed:

[image]

After installing brownie and running slither:

[image]